# Why is my React application not loading even though there are no errors in the terminal?

Tags: reactjs, localhost

https://github.com/KunalWalavalkar/React-Workout-App.git

So this is the application. When I run it on the local host it loads for a brief second and then disappears. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: you have a lots of errors actually https://imgur.com/a/gJvPNnM